Can I use the Sheets command to change font colors based on PASS/FAIL?
I use the following code to determine a PASS/FAIL in VB

Sheets(1).Cells(rwcount, qccolcnt + 1).Value = Sheets(sheet_number).Cells(6, tempcount).Value

This Sheets command grabs a "PASS" or "FAIL" and populates a Cell in another sheet. I want to change the Fonts in this other sheet Cell to Green or Red, respectively.
Any help is appreciated.

How about using conditional formatting instead of vba code?

Does Sheets command mean Sheets(sheet_number).Cells(6, tempcount).Value? to change the Fonts in this Cell What's this cell?

So I'm going to a certain sheet row/column and grabbing the string in that Cell.  The string is the stored on Sheet 1 in a certain location.  I want to change the color of the string (Text), at that sheet 1 location to red if the string is FALSE.

this works, If Sheets(1).Cells(rwcount, qccolcnt + 1) = "FAIL" Then
Cells(rwcount, qccolcnt + 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 50, 25)
End If

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This also replaces you existing line
With Sheets(1).Cells(rwcount, qccolcnt + 1)
    .Value = Sheets(sheet_number).Cells(6, tempcount).Value
    If .Value = "PASS" Then .Font.Color = vbGreen
    If .Value = "FAIL" Then .Font.Color = vbRed
End With

